# SharePoint 2013 - One or more services have started or stopped unexpectedly - SPTimerV4

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I'm getting this error message in CA. I checked the timer service and it is up and running. I tried with "Repair Automatically" but use.

**ULS Error**

> The following services are managed by SharePoint, but their running
>   state does not match what SharePoint expects:
>   FIMSynchronizationService.  This can happen if a service crashes or if
>   an administrator starts or stops a service using a non-SharePoint
>   interface.  If SharePoint-managed services do not match their expected
>   running state, SharePoint will be unable to correctly distribute work
>   to the service.. Automatic repair is being attempted.

Comment: Have you checked the Windows event logs as well? The Application and System log may contain relevant information.

Comment: Hi Nadeem, unfortunately there isn't any errors in the system log. I've tried the steps in [this](http://mundeep.wordpress.com/2012/08/13/clearing-timer-services/) blog but it is not fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar problem by starting search service from PowerShell:

```
$host1 = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Identity "YourServerName"
Start-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Identity $host1
```